# Regarding showing showing only row of specific field value if there is more than one value in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that shows all the orders. However, if an order was cancelled, I get two rows: one with status Paid and one with status Cancelled.

What should I do to make it only give me the Cancelled row in case there are both Paid and Cancelled rows? The query:

```sql
SELECT *
EXCEPT (main_category, sub_category, category_id, parent_category_id),
  MAX(main_category) AS Main_Category,
  MAX(sub_category) AS Sub_Category
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT
    status.modified_date AS Modified_Date,
    orders.id AS Order_ID,
    items.id AS Item_ID,
    products.product_id AS Product_ID,
    products.name AS Product_Title,
    products.margin AS Margin,
    items.price AS Item_Price,
    orders.total_price AS Total_Price,
    "Cancelled" AS Status, -- Always set to "Cancelled"
    CAST(orders.created_date AS DATETIME) AS Order_Date,
    orders.order_user_id AS User_ID,
    orders.firstname AS First_Name,
    orders.lastname AS Last_Name,
    orders.telephone AS Telephone,
    orders.email AS Email,
    orders.website_id AS Website_ID,
    products.date_available AS Date_Live,
    vendor.vendor_id AS Vendor_ID,
    IFNULL(vencomp.store_page, vendor.vendor_name) AS Vendor_Name,
    CAST(vendor.created_date AS DATETIME) AS Vendor_Date,
    cat.category_id AS Category_ID,
    cat.parent_int AS Parent_Category_ID,
    CASE
      WHEN cat.lob_name = "shopping" THEN "שופינג"
      WHEN cat.lob_name = "local" THEN "לוקאל"
      WHEN cat.lob_name = "travel" THEN "תיירות"
    END AS LOB,
    agents.agent_name AS Agent_Name,
    ship.id AS Shipping_ID,
    ship.title AS Shipping_Method,
    CAST(ship.cost AS INT64) AS Shipping_Price,
    products.is_active AS Is_Active,
    EXTRACT(DATETIME FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(items.expiration_date)) AS Voucher_Exp_Date,
    CASE
      WHEN vendor.approval_flag = 1 THEN "Active"
      ELSE "Not Active"
    END AS Vendor_Status,
    cat.sub_sub_category_title AS Sub2_Category,
    cat.sub_sub_sub_category_title AS Sub3_Category,
    items.voucher_id AS Voucher_ID,
    items.voucher_code AS Voucher_Code,
    items.security_code AS Security_Code,
    ref.id AS Refund_ID,
    ref.reason AS Refund_Reason,
    ref.method AS Refund_Method,
    ref.comment AS Refund_Comment,
    ref.amount AS Refund_Amount,
    ref.created_date AS Refund_Date,
    cat.main_category_title AS Main_Category,
    cat.sub_category_title AS Sub_Category,
    items.status AS Item_Status,
    CASE
      WHEN status.status = 'REFUNDED' THEN status.modified_date
      ELSE NULL
    END AS Cancel_Date
  FROM
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.m1_groo_prod_spurt.order` AS orders
  LEFT JOIN
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.m1_groo_prod_spurt.order_item` AS items
  ON
    orders.id = items.order_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.m1_groo_prod_spurt.order_item_status_log` AS status
  ON
    status.order_item_id = items.id
  LEFT JOIN
    `m1_groo_prod_spurt.product` AS products
  ON
    items.product_id = products.product_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `m1_groo_prod_spurt.product_to_category` AS catprod
  ON
    items.product_id = catprod.product_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.Groo_Bi_Reports.Categories Hierarchy` AS cat
  ON
    cat.category_id = catprod.category_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `m1_groo_prod_spurt.vendor` AS vendor
  ON
    vendor.vendor_id = orders.vendor_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `m1_groo_prod_spurt.vendor_company_information` AS vencomp
  ON
    vencomp.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id
  LEFT JOIN
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.m1_groo_prod_spurt.shipping_methods` AS ship
  ON
    CAST(ship.id AS STRING) = orders.shipping_methods
  LEFT JOIN
    `Groo_Bi_Reports.Agent_Names` AS agents
  ON
    agents.Agent_ID = products.agent_name
  LEFT JOIN
    `gcommerce-m1-prod.m1_groo_prod_spurt.refund_details` AS ref
  ON
    ref.id = items.refund_id
  WHERE
    orders.migrated_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM `Groo_Bi_Reports.Unicorn_Main_View`
)
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
```

Tried to play with Status Counting etc but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a window function to filter what you need.

Based on what you need, you have to filter based on the order status. It would have been great if you shared your data structure alongside your query so I could have provided you with a better answer. But in short, what you can do is something similar to below:

```
SELECT {{YOUR_COLUMNS}} FROM {{YOUR_TABLE}} 
WHERE {{YOUR_CONDITIONS}}
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY Modified_Date DESC) = 1
```

It will select your columns from your table and then select the last order status for each `order_id`. This answer assumes that each `order_id` is unique.

**Explanation of the code**

`QUALIFY` is acting just like where

`ROW_NUMBER()` it is a function where creates islands of rows then numbers them

`OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY Modified_Date DESC)` this is saying that the islands must be created per `order_id`. if an order has two record, then sort them based on the `Modified_Date` and sort it DESC

`= 1` is saying that just keep the last one (meaning that if the order has a paid and cancelled status, keep the last one).

If you need more information, please check Big Query's documentation for `ROW_NUMBER()` and `QUALIFY`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. What should my conditions look like if i want it to show only the Cancelled row in case there is both Paid and Cancelled rows for the same items?

Comment: You can use qualify and sub-queries. Either add one COUNT(Modified_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) > 2 or create a subquery/ a cte where you only order with more than 1 status and run what I have shown you above.